# Font Distortion on Windows Browsers

Tags: css, fonts

Text is distorting and becoming unreadable, but it is happening only in Windows browsers, both FireFox and Chrome.  I am trying to reproduce the problem with a sample of the text with the styles in effect on the distorted text, but the sample looks ok.

Link to text that is distorted on windows Firefox and Windows Chrome:
http://dansdemos.info/prelaunch/hitch/20140219_1735/bk_promos/mergecopy
You've already invested in creating a great book...

Link to sample that is supposed to have same styles, but does not distort in windows Firefox and Windows Chrome:
http://dansdemos.info/prelaunch/hitch/20140219_1735/bk_promos/hammeredShitTextProblem

The styles in effect are:

```
p {
color: #777777;
font-size: 14px;
letter-spacing: 0.1px;
line-height: 23px;
width: 307px;
font-family: open sans,arial;
}
* {
border: 0 none;
margin: 0;
outline: 0 none;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
}
*::-moz-placeholder {
color: #666666;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 300;
```

}

Any ideas on why the text is distorted in Windows only?  And why it is not distorted in the sample with the same styles?

Comment: It's got something to do with the open sans font.  If you inspect the distorted elements, and remove the open sans font, the distortion goes  away.  Don't know why the sample page is not distorted.  Is it referencing the same open sans web font?

Comment: Thank you HaukurlHaf.  Adding the reference to open sans in the sample now, expecting to see the distortion.

Comment: Switched to just arial font, problem solved.  Thank you.

Comment: You should specify what you mean by “distorted” and analyze what the difference between the codes actually is. There is probably a real problem behind this (though probably of a kind frequently presented here, with the answer “font rendering varies”).